# How to get the main method to give output from public passing command argument in C#/

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and having problems passing input data from the static Main method to another method command-line public static. Below is the code in visual studio 2019. I have the input data and the code should return the calcPay value but doesn't. It only enters the value declared in the initialization of the variable.

````
namespace CalcGrossPay
{
    class Salary
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double myHours = 0;
            double myRate = 0; 
            double grossPay;
            grossPay = CalcPay(myHours, myRate);


            Console.WriteLine("Enter total hours worked: ");
            myHours = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter rate per hour: ");
            myRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Number of hours worked is {0} at {1} per hour", myHours, myRate);

            Console.WriteLine("My gross pay is\n {0:F2}", grossPay.ToString("c"));
        }
          public static double CalcPay(double hours, double rate)
            {
                double pay;

                // If hours>40
                // Get gross pay by calculating overtime
                if (hours > 40)
                {
                    pay = 40 * rate + (1.5 * rate * (hours - 40));
                }
                else
                {
                    pay = hours * rate;
                }
                return pay;
            }
        
    }
}```
````

Comment: You should invoke CalcPay AFTER "Number of hours worked" console writeline. Obviously it calculates grossPay ignoring your input (using default ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CalcPay`method is only call once and that is when the variables are set to 0
Change the methode like this

```
namespace CalcGrossPay
{
    class Salary
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double myHours = 0;
            double myRate = 0; 
            double grossPay;
            


            Console.WriteLine("Enter total hours worked: ");
            myHours = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter rate per hour: ");
            myRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Number of hours worked is {0} at {1} per hour", myHours, myRate);

            grossPay = CalcPay(myHours, myRate);
            Console.WriteLine("My gross pay is\n {0:F2}", grossPay.ToString("c"));
        }
          public static double CalcPay(double hours, double rate)
            {
                double pay;

                // If hours>40
                // Get gross pay by calculating overtime
                if (hours > 40)
                {
                    pay = 40 * rate + (1.5 * rate * (hours - 40));
                }
                else
                {
                    pay = hours * rate;
                }
                return pay;
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the error. I also finally understand a bit of the method invoking concept. Thank you again.